# Android Studio constantly crashing on Mac M1 in 2024

Tags: android-studio

I am using Android Studio on my MacBook M1, but it constantly crashes. Every time I start using it, it crashes. Most often this happened when I had to use the emulator. I have tried many different versions of the emulator API and nothing helps. I am working with Android Studio Hedgehog. I've also tried with the Giraffe version as well as the Iguana beta, the problem persists and nothing helps. Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this problem and use my Android Studio without problems together with the emulator. What should I change?
Also an interesting detail is that when I turn on Spotify on the computer and when I try to turn on the emulator, the sound in the headphones changes and becomes lower quality.
I am attaching the report I get every time after each crash:

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               studio [7747]
Path:                  /Users/USER/*/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
Identifier:            com.google.android.studio
Version:               2022.3 (AI-223.8836.35.2231.10811636)
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2024-01-21 13:34:57.4550 +0200
OS Version:            macOS 14.2.1 (23C71)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        1D41965D-901B-AC31-4DDE-912A21604E2C

Sleep/Wake UUID:       2EA9BDCB-B9C5-44DA-8CEC-B3CB1D4F5629

Time Awake Since Boot: 6800 seconds
Time Since Wake:       3393 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        24  Java: GC Thread#5

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000100000000
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100000000

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process:   studio [7747]

VM Region Info: 0x100000000 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 70303744
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                      10430c000-104314000    [   32K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  .../MacOS/studio

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Kernel Triage:
VM - (arg = 0x0) Decompressor hit a failure
```

Comment: Having the same problem. Shutting down and restarting also doesn't help. As soon as I would start Android Studio, even without booting an emulator, it would crash my system.

I'm observing the memory. And never uses all of the system's memory. There is always at least 2GB left.

Comment: To add another comment, that could improve the situation. I restricted memory usage from Android Studio to 1024MB in its app settings. It will complain, but I don't care as long as it keeps spawning processes and makes my system crash.

Comment: I downgraded to Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2 to make it work :)

Answer (score -1):

The following solution won't resolve the underlying issue, but it will eventually help those who are desperate and frustrated about not being able to run Android Studio.

I'm solving this issue by moving to VSCode.
Comparing VSCode with Android Studio it doesn't use as much memory.
A note on the memory topic. My colleagues and I have observed, right before crashing, it has never reached the full capacity of memory. So we are not sure, this is the issue. Also, Mac tends to turn off peripheric devices, such as wifi and Bluetooth before freezing/crashing.

In VSCode I asked myself, how can I run emulators?
It has plugins and you can choose one of your liking.
I installed the [Android iOS Emulator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DiemasMichiels.emulate).

You probably have some emulators downloaded with Android Studio Code and Xcode. When following the instructions of the Emulator you can start the emulators. Right now I am running iOS and Android at the same time.
When you then run `flutter run` it will ask you on which emulator you like to start the app. Opening another terminal tap, you can run the command again and choose the other emulator and you will have the app running on hot-reload on both iOS and Android.

It takes me around about 11GB of memory. 1,5GB less, because VSCode takes less memory than Android Studio.

Running flavours, follow the [VSCode setup instructions here](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors#setting-up-launch-configurations).

I have no solution for signing yet since I did it with Android Studio. But when we guess, it has something to do with its own emulator, we might be able to avoid the emulator and just use its signing capabilities. There are also automated signing options.